# How to access a mail in Gmail Through watir webdriver

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am facing a problem that  I am not able to select and open a particular mail in gmail through `watir webdriver`. Can anyone help me for the same.
Task I want to perform:-

1. Login to gmail--- Done
2. Select a mail by its subject line --- Not done need help for this
3. Sign-out   -- Done

Comment: You may get better answers if you show what you tried and the results (ie exceptions, observations, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The email subject line is in a <span> tag, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
b.text_field(:id => "Email").set "your_email"
b.text_field(:id => "Passwd").set "your_password"
b.button(:id => "signIn").click

b.span(:text => /your_email_subject_line/).click
```

Then again, this is a fragile solution, and gmail is notoriously difficult to automate against. So your mileage may vary...